# Can't change "owner permission" for lots of files on Windows 11

Tags: windows, permissions

Windows 11. Dell Latitude 7430.

I'm trying to use the "dir/s/b" command in Command Prompt on all the root-directories in my "C:" drive so that I can get a summary of every file held on the computer.

It seems that if I don't have "access permission" to certain files then this command will skip those files.

I'm having a very hard time trying to configure MY computer to give me absolute unrestricted permission to all the files on it.

I've got as far as changing the "owner" of the "C:" drive to myself in the advanced security settings and checking the "apply to child 'containers' too" box, and highlighting my user—which nominally has "full permission" over everything—in that box with a bunch of placeholder users for good measure. When I click "apply" it seems to start running through every single file on the computer; but very quickly it just starts coming up against HUNDREDS if not THOUSANDS of files that just won't let their permissions be changed. It just throws up a "permission can't be changed. access denied" message for every single one, prompting me to press enter in order for it to continue.

Comment: You're trying hard to destroy your Windows installation. If you would have taken ownership of every folder in C: you will have had to reinstall Windows.

Comment: You have not explained **why** you want to do what you are trying to do. Listen to @harrymc, this is a very bad idea.

Comment: Your operating system, like every major modern operating system, is trying to protect you from programs and code doing unexpected things such as modifying the system, as well as preventing other users who may be set up on your machine from accessing your files. You might as well install Windows 98 SE, which is provably the best OS ever released apart from it being completely unreliable and insecure. Yes, your computer is yours, you can do what you like with it, but the protections in place are for your benefit and have a reason for existing beyond "stopping you from seeing all the files".

Comment: @Gantendo yes you're right, I didn't. Basically I'm doing a thorough back-up and wanted to be sure I hadn't accidentally saved some file months ago in some obscure corner of the OS and then forgotten about it. Also I want to in general become better acquainted with the OS, so with this data I'd be able to make a kind of visual map of "C:\" to show me its rough 'layout', i guess.

Comment: @harrymc yes you're right, i see that now. was in the process of re-installing anyway so it'll be alright. i've already "corrupted the recycling bin"!

Comment: @Mokubai yes, thanks for informing me there. i can appreciate now that there are reasons for it besides dumb ones, which i'll learn about as i study more.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is, "get a summary of every file held on the computer," you've gone about that the wrong way. Likely, if you've taken ownership of some key Windows files and folders, the operating system has been damaged **and** made insecure. The safest thing to do, before going further, is to make a drive image, lest something go wrong, and then **reinstall [Windows from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11),** keeping files.

The *safe* and *easy* way to examine *everything* on your drive is to make a drive image and then look at that image. [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macrium_reflect_free_edition.html), for example, can mount (open) an image and [enable access to restricted folders](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW/Browsing+Macrium+Reflect+images+and+backups+in+Windows+Explorer). See [AskWoody](https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/how-to-set-permission-to-access-all-users-files-on-a-backup-image/) on this, too.

Comment: thanks. I'll try and make a "disk image" in that way and come back with what i find.